# Can not use.Netcore App 2.14 framework for another VS 2017 projects Except ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

i want install [nopcommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com) 4.0 and develop it so i have downloaded project and opened it by VS 2017 version 1.5.3 and also i have installed .Net core SDK 2.1.4.

after rebuilding soloution i see 705 errors that for resolve a part of them i decide to set the target framework to .Netcore App 2.1.4.

but according to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NApDE.jpg) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7SB3.jpg) attached images ,there is not .Netcore App 2.14 in target framework!

but when i create a new ASP.NET core web application,i can see .Netcore App 1.1 in my target framework!

please help me!

Comment: You cannot convert a .NET Framework application into a .NET Core one like that. Not sure what you think that's going to solve either

Comment: NopCommerce 4 targets full framework. It doesn't support .NET Core yet.